# Drop-down from an object list with Tapestry

Tags: list, object, tapestry

Actually I've got a UserCred Property on my Tapestry 5.3.7 App...

Is there any way to show a drop-down list of objects instead of enums on a beaneditform?

Thanks guys... I've been looking for any solution, but most of them seems outdated and hard to understand for my poor mind T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tapestry needs two main things to render a [Select](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Select.html)

1. A [SelectModel](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/SelectModel.html) to determine the values in the list
2. A [ValueEncoder](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ValueEncoder.html) to know how to render clientside keys which convert to serverside values.

Notes:

1. You can @Inject the [SelectModelFactory](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/SelectModelFactory.html) to generate a SelectModel from a list of objects.
2. There's also an [EnumSelectModel](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/util/EnumSelectModel.html) to help with enums.
3. If you don't explicitly provide a ValueEncoder, tapestry will attempt to find one using the [ValueEnvoderSource](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/ValueEncoderSource.html) (tapestry-hibernate automagically creates ValueEncoders for all of your entities)
4. If you pass `model` parameter which is not an instance of `SelectModel`, tapestry will attempt to [type-coerce](http://tapestry.apache.org/typecoercer-service.html) the value to a SelectModel. There are a couple of built-in coercions for String, List and Map.